# 時、分、秒に区分されている各々の行を一つの行としてまとめたいです。

Tags: python, python3

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようなdataframe型のデータがあります。
このデータから日付と時刻のデータをyyyy-mm-dd H:M:S型の一つのデータとしてまとめたいですが、
時刻のデータが全部同じ6桁でしたら、strftimeを使いhh:mm:ssとして分けられたかもしれませんが、
元のデータが0秒から始まる桁数が一致しないデータになっておりまして

```
df['hh']=np.floor(df['時刻']/10000)　
df['mm']=np.floor((df['時刻']-df['hh']*10000)/100)
df['ss']=df['時刻']-df['hh']*10000-df['mm']*100
df['日付']=pd.to_datetime(df['日付'],format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

上記のように求めました。
その次にhh、mm、ssを一つのデータとしてまとめ日付データの後ろにくっつけたいですが
どうすればいいでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zfill`による前ゼロ埋めで全部同じ6桁にして、日付データの後ろにくっつけることができます。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ '日付': '2018-04-14',
                    '時刻': [0, 100, 235859] })
df['日付時刻'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日付'] + df['時刻'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S')
print(df['日付時刻'])

"""
0   2018-04-14 00:00:00
1   2018-04-14 00:01:00
2   2018-04-14 23:58:59
Name: 日付時刻, dtype: datetime64[ns]
"""
```

Comment: 助かりました。pythonには本当に様々な機能がありますね。びっくりしました。しっかり解決できました。ありがとうございます